# Concatenate lines between double forward slashes

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
//

ABC

String1

String2

BDF:
ssss

//

AFG

String4

String9

BDF:
fff 

//
```

I would like the output to be

```
ABC, String1, String2, BDF: ssss
AFG, String4, String9, BDF: fff
```

How do I grep just the lines between the double forward slashes and concatenate the separate chunks in to one line? Please note the lines in between forward slashes vary throughout the file.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was for formatting purposes. Its not meant to be in the file

Comment: You should test the answers you get with `:` in various positions in the input.

Answer (score 4):

try with GNU `awk` that allows setting RS to multiple chars and set to double slash `//`; then print the fields with comma delimited by setting `OFS=', '` and return colon-comma to colon with `gsub()`; the purpose of setting `$1=$1` is to trigger awk to rebuild the fields based on OFS set then `print`.

```
awk -v RS='//' 'NF{ $1=$1; gsub(":,", ":"); print }' OFS=', ' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

With any standard awk:

```
/^\/\//{                 #If this line begins with //
    sub(/:,/,":",line)   #Substitute :, with :
    if(line){print line} #If `line` is not blank, print it
    line=""              #Reset `line`
    next                 #Start next cycle with next line
}
#If current line not empty, append it to `line` with separator if `line` not empty
!/^$/{line=(line?line", ":"")$0}
```

Save the above script (for example, as `joinlines.awk`) and run it on the input file:

```
$ awk -f joinlines.awk file
ABC, String1, String2, BDF: ssss
AFG, String4, String9, BDF: fff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0 == "//" {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        print rec
    }
    rec = sep = ""
    next
}
NF { rec = rec (prevNF ? " " : sep) $0; sep=", " }
{ prevNF = NF }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ABC, String1, String2, BDF: ssss
AFG, String4, String9, BDF: fff
```

Answer (score 0):

With the awk editor based on the current record and a boolean flag f, we manipulate the output record separator.

```
awk '
! NF || /^\/\/$/ { f=""; next }
{
  ORS = ! f && ! /:/ ? ", "        \
      : ! f &&   /:/ ? (f=" ")  \
      : RS
}1' file
```

With the Perl we operate in the paragraph mode

```
perl -F'\n' -aln -00 -e '$"=", ";
  m{\A//$}m and
    print reverse pop @F, "@F[1..$#F] ";
' file
```

Using the python 3 interpreter

```
python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
  for line in fh:
      line = line.rstrip("\n")
      if   line == "//": L = []
      elif line != "":   L += [line]
      elif len(L):
        print(", ".join(L[:-1])+" "+L[-1])
        L = []
  if len(L): print(", ".join(L[:-1])+" "+L[-1])
' file
```

Using GNU sed

```
sed -e '
   /\n/bb
    /\/\//,/^$/!d
    /./!ba
   \|//|!H;$!d
    :a;z;x;D
    :b;s/:\n/: /;s/\n/, /g
  ' file
```

**output**

```
ABC, String1, String2, BDF: ssss
AFG, String4, String9, BDF: ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tot=`sed '/\/\//d' inputfile| sed '/^$/d'| awk 'END{print NR}'`
sed '/\/\//d' inputfile| sed '/^$/d' > finalfile

for ((i=1;i<=$tot;i++)); do z=$(($i + 4)); sed -n ''$i','$z'p' finalfile| perl -pne "s/\n/, /g"; i=$z;echo -e "\n"; done|sed '/^$/d'| awk '{gsub(",","",$NF);print $0}'| sed "s/:,/:/g"
```

output

```
ABC, String1, String2, BDF: ssss
AFG, String4, String9, BDF: fff
```